# OpenSSL - Internally using the wrong certificates, externally is fine

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am seeing an odd issue with two of our externally facing systems where access over the web on HTTPS works, and uses the correct COMODO certificates, but internally it is using self-signed certificates.

The command being used to test this is:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect wiki.domain.com:443
```

Externally, this returns:

```
    Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard/CN=*.domain.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
```

Internally (from the local subnet) I see:

```
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=Somewhere/L=Somecity/O=CompanyName/OU=Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)/CN=Common Name (eg, YOUR name)/emailAddress=Email Address
issuer=/C=US/ST=Somewhere/L=Somecity/O=CompanyName/OU=Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)/CN=Common Name (eg, YOUR name)/emailAddress=Email Address
```

Any idea why this would be happening please? I can't figure out what's going on here.

Please ask if you need further details, am happy to provide. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Sorry, just realised I went to the wrong URL (stackoverflow instead of stackexchange).